# Batch: concatenate variable and string to form output path

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file where a user enters a path to a file and I extract the filename form that path.

I use that filename to create a folder of the same name.

In that folder, I want to create a log.txt file that the process I am calling in my batch file can write its log messages to.

Here's the code:

```
set /p pathFoFile="Enter path fo file: "
FOR %%i IN ("%pathFoFile%") DO (
    set outputFolder=%%~ni
)

someprocess -p1 blabla -p2 blabla -p3 %outputFolder% > %outputFolder%\log.txt
```

The last part, `%outputFolder%\log.txt`, seems to be the problem, since it works when I just put `> log.txt`

However, when I echo this:

```
echo %outputFolder%\log.txt
```

it prints the correct path.

How can I use the foldername and create this log.txt file?

**EDIT**

The path I get may look like this:

```
..\some\folder\thefile.egf
```

or just

```
thefile.egf
```

or an absolute path.

I extract the

```
thefile
```

and would like to call:

```
someprocess -p1 blabla -p2 blabla -p3 thefile > thefile\log.txt
```

the folder `thefile` containing `log.txt` should be created relative to the batch file. There are no drive letters in the path.

The error I get when using `%outputFolder%\log.txt` or `"%outputFolder%\log.txt"` is that the system cannot find the path.

Comment: I tried this exact script with `dir` instead of `someprocess` and it worked fine.  Does the path you typed include the drive letter and no trailing slash?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: I think I got it: The folder is created by the process. And the process takes a little time to create the folder. And when I do > folder/log.txt, the folder hasn't been created yet... That's probably it.

Comment: You cannot redirect into a folder that does not yet exist, so you need to do `mkdir "%outputFolder%"` before redirecting like `> "%outputFolder%\log.txt"`. (Put quotes around all paths to avoid trouble with potential white-spaces or special characters.)

Answer (score 2):

Use quotes in case you have spaces in path.

```
someprocess -p1 blabla -p2 blabla -p3 "%outputFolder%" > "%outputFolder%\log.txt"
```

Comment: This didn't work. I still get the same error. And I can't have spaces in the path because the filename won't have spaces. And I am using the filename as the foldername.

Comment: Most likely the folder does not exist. What does 'SomeProcess do? Is it supposed to create the folder? If not do MD "%OutFolder%"

Answer (score 0):

`%%~dpni` will expand the variable to include the drive, path, and filename.