# batch to concatenate %var_1% and "VarText"

Tags: windows, batch-file

Goal: In a batch file, append or concatenate the text in `Var_1` with the string `JpgList`and add the extension `.txt` to the output file

In the batch this works

```
Dir *.Jpg > JpgList.txt
```

In the batch, I have already retrieved a Variable `%Var_1%`

Problem is: concatenating the `Var` with the literal string `JpgList` and appending `.txt` as the output filename.

Here are code examples of what I have tried along with pseudo code that fails, *(Some produce a .txt file with no name, some produce nothing and some produce a file with the `Var_1` name, but no content in file)*.

`dir *.jpg Var_1 + jpgList.txt`
`dir > %label_% >>".txt"`
`dir > %%label_%% >>".txt"`

I have tried every which way but upside down to put this together, and
appreciate any tips or syntax for making the code work.

Comment: [Edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48243463/edit) to include the batch file content you want help with, not just some individual commands which you say didn't work.

Comment: Use the command line: `dir *.jpg>"%Var_1%JpgList.txt"` The string concatenation is done by Windows command interpreter `cmd.exe` which replaces (expands) `%Var_1%` by value of this environment variable during preprocessing phase of the command line before executing command __DIR__.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve.  Please take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].  Edit your question to meet SO standards.  @Mofi has probably surmised what you are trying to do and given the likely answer, but all is of no use to anybody else if you don't fix your post.

Comment: You should also try [searching for answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5Dconcatenate+variable+string) before posting.  You problem has been asked and answered many times, [including this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122258/batch-concatenate-variable-and-string-to-form-output-path).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch: concatenate variable and string to form output path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122258/batch-concatenate-variable-and-string-to-form-output-path)

Comment: Thanks to Mofi for the simple solution= dir *.jpg>"%Var_1%JpgList.txt The way I will use this is for fetching files from back ups on the many internal and external drives I have.  By placing the drive volume/ID var in the filename, I can catalog all of my files with names that ID the drive.  At the root of the drive I will execute a batch to go through the entire drive and list each file with extensions I want TO SEARCH FOR LATER.  The batch will have dir/s *.ext > >"%Var_1%extList.txt where ext can be bmp doc, whatever.  All logged files can then be searched by Agent Ransack or other engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you haven't provided your batch file, we have no idea of the possible content of `%Var_1%` or `%label_%` so answers currently need to speculate.

The following should work, as long as the content of `%Var_1%` does not include problematic/disallowed characters or a non-existent/inaccessble location.

```bat
Dir /B/A-D-L *.jpg>"%Var_1%JpgList.txt"
```